# html5 canvas clicking on bezier path shape detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, click

I have a canvas with some irregular shape drawings in it, and I would like to have a feedback when someone clicks on a specific one?

I've been looking everywhere for this and have only found solutions for rectangle.

I think it may have to do with isPointInPath(), but I've yet to find a concise explanation on how to use it.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 13):

I made a tutorial that uses a second invisible canvas to do object picking/hit testing. Draw all your shapes, one by one, onto the second canvas until one of them has a black pixel where the mouse location is. Then you've found your object!

Here's a bit from the tutorial I wrote on selecting objects with canvas:

```
  // gctx is ghost context, made from the second canvas
  // clear(gctx)

  // ...

  // run through all the boxes
  var l = boxes.length;
  for (var i = l-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // draw shape onto ghost context
    drawshape(gctx, boxes[i], 'black', 'black');

    // get image data at the mouse x,y pixel
    var imageData = gctx.getImageData(mx, my, 1, 1);
    var index = (mx + my * imageData.width) * 4;

    // if the mouse pixel exists, select and break
    if (imageData.data[3] > 0) {
      mySel = boxes[i];
      offsetx = mx - mySel.x;
      offsety = my - mySel.y;
      mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
      mySel.y = my - offsety;
      isDrag = true;
      canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
      invalidate();
      clear(gctx);
      return;
    }

  }
```

My full demo only uses rectangles but in a later version I will use circles/paths/text.

If you want to see the demo and my full code it is [here](http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes).

Comment: Thanks.

I finally did something similar, though I stayed on the save canvas, not doing any strokes or fills while redrawing the shapes.

Comment: @Simon Sarris I have used your tutorial to make this: http://edumax.org.ro/extra/new/mindmap/ (use grid as map and right click for menu)  I am trying to make paths selectable too by using your method. I understand you have a tutorial on this coming up but is there a way you could give us a hint on some basic steps you will follow? (specifically for the path .contains() function)

Comment: Sorry, nearly all my free time right now is spent writing a book, I will get back to my web tutorial series probably around the end of this year. Making paths selectable can be done with the context's `isPointInPath` function but you have to save all the steps needed to make every path and load up the current path of the context every time you need to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pathiterator, that turns all shapes into approximated polygons.
Then use a 'point in polygon' algorithm to check if the point is in the shape.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived by using Path2D.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("result");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var path1 = new Path2D();
path1.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
path1.closePath();
ctx.stroke(path1);

var path2 = new Path2D();
path2.moveTo(220, 60);
path2.arc(170, 60, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
path2.closePath();
ctx.stroke(path2);

var path3 = new Path2D("M230 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z");
ctx.fill(path3);
path3.closePath();

$('canvas').click( function(event) 
{
  div.innerHTML = "";
  
  var x = event.pageX;
  var y = event.pageY;

  if (ctx.isPointInPath(path1, x, y))
    div.innerHTML = "Path1 clicked";

  if (ctx.isPointInPath(path2, x, y))
    div.innerHTML = "Path2 clicked";
  
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(path3, x, y))
    div.innerHTML = "Path3 clicked";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```