# Mouse Over Bezier Curve

Tags: javascript, html, events, canvas, bezier

Is there any easy integrated way to detect a mouseover event on a curve? 
I wish to add bezier curves to the canvas as movable and editable elements and I need a way to select them.

I would rather not use any external libraries (for educational purposes);

Comment: possible duplicate of [html5 canvas clicking on bezier path shape detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518814/html5-canvas-clicking-on-bezier-path-shape-detection)

Answer (score 2):

This answer was written several years ago and since kinetic.js is no longer maintained and the links don't work.

You can try concrete.js (http://www.concretejs.com).

> I would check the kinetic.js library. It is html5 canvas library, that supports many features including curve detection. You can try some examples here:
>
> http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-curve-detection-tutorial/
>
> http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-physics-engine-with-curve-detection/
>
> http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-modify-curves-with-anchor-points-using-kineticjs/
>
> If you do not want to use other libraries and still have great speed, you could try the following approach.

Comment: All of these links yield a `404` for me.