# Fill Closed Are using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have drawn some graphics using html5 canvas.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.stroke = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(30, 30);
ctx.lineTo(150, 150);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(60, 70, 60, 70, 70, 150);
ctx.lineTo(30, 30);
ctx.fill();
```

When I click the canvas area, if the click point is in a closed area, I would like to fill the closed area with color red.

Help me, please

Comment: Do you want to implement [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)?

Comment: Check out the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11815227/573218

Comment: check http://jsbin.com/omuwor/3/edit , please. in here you can see fill and draw button.   after clicking "draw" button, you can draw pen. 
after clicking "fill" button, you have to set the fill color about the draw area

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zsal/FfdCe/2/

Here is a jsfiddle with your canvas filled red on hover.

Comment: check http://jsbin.com/omuwor/3/edit , please. in here you can see fill and draw button. after clicking "draw" button, you can draw pen. after clicking "fill" button, you have to set the fill color about the draw area